# Why doesn't math \fontdimen's work with XeTeX?

Tags: spacing, xetex, tex-core, superscripts, font-metrics

Why doesn't the `\fontdimen`-command change anything with XeTeX?

```
\input pgffor
\def\chfndims#1{\foreach\dim in{13,...,19}{\fontdimen\dim#1=20pt}}
\font\mymathfn="XITS Math:script=math" at 10pt \chfndims\mymathfn
\font\mymathfns="XITS Math:script=math;+ssty=0" at 7pt \chfndims\mymathfns
\font\mymathfnss="XITS Math:script=math;+ssty=1" at 5pt \chfndims\mymathfnss
\textfont0=\mymathfn \scriptfont0=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont0=\mymathfnss
\textfont1=\mymathfn \scriptfont1=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont1=\mymathfnss
\textfont2=\mymathfn \scriptfont2=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont2=\mymathfnss
\textfont3=\mymathfn \scriptfont3=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont3=\mymathfnss
\textfont4=\mymathfn \scriptfont4=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont4=\mymathfnss
\textfont5=\mymathfn \scriptfont5=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont5=\mymathfnss
\textfont6=\mymathfn \scriptfont6=\mymathfns \scriptscriptfont6=\mymathfnss
$ a^b \, c_d \, e^1 \, f_2 $
\bye
```

Nothing changes.

I would like to change the horizontal space before a superscript.

Comment: I don't think that there's a fontdimen for that. Not among the 22 fontdimen parameters of the font in family 2. There's `\scriptspace` for the space *after* a sub/superscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no font dimension parameter that controls the spacing before a subscript/superscript: they are attached to the atom they refer, possibly shifted horizontally based on the information provided by the atom, if it's a character box. The parameter `\scriptspace` controls the space *after* them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if XeTeX does not support setting fontdimens related to maths (ie. sub-/superscript height)?

Comment: I've tried the chemical formula example in the TeXbook and it doesn't work like advertised. :( Perhaps Will is more expert in the matter.