# Subscript placement with unicode-math

Tags: xetex, subscripts, unicode-math

I'm running into an issue when using boxes in subscripts with `unicode-math` loaded.

I drafted the following MWE from my package [`actuarialsymbol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol). [Command `\qx` below puts subscripts on both sides of a symbol; the subscripts should be bottom aligned.]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{unicode-math}

 \makeatletter
 \def\qx[#1]#2{
   \fboxsep=0pt % for debugging purposes
   \setbox\@ne\hbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}
   \setbox\thr@@\hbox{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}
   \ifdim \ht\@ne>\ht\thr@@
     \ht\thr@@=\ht\@ne
   \else
     \ht\@ne=\ht\thr@@
   \fi
   \vphantom{q}\sb{\fbox{\box\@ne}}%
   q\sb{\fbox{\box\thr@@}}%
 }
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

$\qx[t]{x}$

\end{document}
```

When compiling with `xetex`, the `t` and `x` on either side of `q` are at different heights:

[image]

Commenting out `unicode-math`, the subscripts are at the same height, as I would expect and as it works with `pdftex`:

[image]

Adding `\the\ht\thr@@` or `\the\ht\@ne` before symbol building solves the positioning issue (but is clearly not a viable solution). Removing the call to `\vphantom` also solves the positioning issue.

I see in the documentation of `unicode-math` that there is some treatment of subscripts in unicode-math with xetex, but I'm honestly at lost as to what I might be doing wrong or how I should fix the issue.

[Placement of subscripts using unicode-math. Is it XeTeX bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40349/placement-of-subscripts-using-unicode-math-is-it-xetex-bug) seems closely related to my issue, but alas nothing there helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see the different shift when `\vphantom` is used. Curiously it disappears if one explictly choose `\textstyle` inside the \vphantom. It looks like another variant of the problem of leaking mathstyles and imho is probably a `xetex` problem and not `unicode math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{unicode-math}


\makeatletter
 \def\qx[#1]#2{
   \fboxsep=0pt % for debugging purposes
   \setbox\@ne\hbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}
   \setbox\thr@@\hbox{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}
   \ifdim \ht\@ne>\ht\thr@@
     \ht\thr@@=\ht\@ne
   \else
     \ht\@ne=\ht\thr@@
   \fi
   \vphantom{q}\sb{\fbox{\box\@ne}}%
   q\sb{\fbox{\box\thr@@}}%
 }
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}



\tikz[overlay]\draw[red] (0,-2.47003pt)--++(10cm,-2.47003pt);
$\vphantom{\textstyle q}\sb{t} q\sb{t}$

\tikz[overlay]\draw[red] (0,-2.47003pt)--++(10cm,-2.47003pt);
$\vphantom{q}\sb{t} q\sb{t}$

\tikz[overlay]\draw[red] (0,-2.47003pt)--++(10cm,-2.47003pt);
$\qx[t]{x}$


\makeatletter
 \def\qx[#1]#2{
   \fboxsep=0pt % for debugging purposes
   \setbox\@ne\hbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}
   \setbox\thr@@\hbox{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}
   \ifdim \ht\@ne>\ht\thr@@
     \ht\thr@@=\ht\@ne
   \else
     \ht\@ne=\ht\thr@@
   \fi
   \vphantom{\textstyle q}\sb{\fbox{\box\@ne}}%
   q\sb{\fbox{\box\thr@@}}%
 }
\makeatother

\tikz[overlay]\draw[red] (0,-2.47003pt)--++(10cm,-2.47003pt);
$\qx[t]{x}$



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `\textstyle` inside `\vphantom` in the macro seems like an entirely satisfactory solution. I can confirm it solves the issue.

Comment: The following question is related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296177/bug-in-xelatex-unicodemath-vphantom. It looks as if the problem was in part resolved in tl2017 but not completly.

Comment: Interestingly, I also notice that, say, `$p_x$` and `$p_x^2$` have their subscript at the same height with `xetex` and `unicode-math`. Probably related to the bug you link to, although I get this behaviour with TL 2017.

Comment: It depends on the height/size of the subscript. "t" is a problem, "x" not. And I think that the bug has been only partially resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\makeatletter
\def\qx[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}%
  \ifdim \ht\z@>\ht\tw@
    \ht\tw@=\ht\z@
  \else
    \ht\z@=\ht\tw@
  \fi
  \vphantom{q}\sb{\box\z@}%
  q\sb{\box\tw@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\debugrule}{%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{%
    \sbox0{$q_x$}\sbox2{$q$}%
    \dimen0=\dp0 \ifdim\dp2>\dp0 \dimen=\dp2\fi
    \vrule depth \dimen0 height \dimexpr0.1pt-\dimen0\relax width 2cm}%
}

\begin{document}

\debugrule$q_tq_x\qx[t]{x}$

\debugrule$\vphantom{q}_{q}q_x\qx[q]{x}$

\debugrule$\vphantom{q}_{t}q_x\qx[t]{x}$

\end{document}
```

The compilation with XeLaTeX yields

[image]

where the misalignment only appears when `\vphantom{q}_t` is used without the adjustment to the height.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention not being able to confirm the issue: using your preamble, `\debugrule$\qx[t]{x}$` yields a misaligned symbol. Actually, `\debugrule$\qx[t]{x}$\qx[t]{x}` even yields a misaligned first symbol... and correct second one.

Comment: @VincentGoulet That's what I get. Maybe an issue due to outdated software?

Comment: @VincentGoulet I mean: I *do* get the misalignment with `\fbox`, but, as you see from the picture, there is good alignment without it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being picky, but I would consider something like the first symbol of your third example as misaligned, if ever so slightly. I tested this on TL 2016 and 2017.

Comment: @VincentGoulet That doesn't use `\qx`, as pointed out in the final paragraph.

Comment: I know, but as mentioned in my first comment, I get the same thing when `\qx` is the first (or only) command in a math expression.